# Suppress negative y-axis in ListLinePlot even if all values are zero?

Tags: plotting

I have some lists that will always contain non-negative values, sometimes all zeros.  Whatever non-negative values appear in the list, I would like the plots to appear without a negative y-axis.  I'll use constant arrays instead of real data for the purpose of this message:

```
ListLinePlot[ConstantArray[0, 640], PlotRange -> {Full, {0, Full}}]
```

[image: zero case]

```
ListLinePlot[ConstantArray[1, 640], PlotRange -> {Full, {0, Full}}]
```

[image: one case]

Ignore the aspect ratios... Doesn't the `{0, Full}` portion of `PlotRange -> {Full, {0, Full}}]` specify that I don't want to see anything under y == 0?  If so, why does the first plot (zeros) produce a negative y-axis and is there any way to suppress it?

Comment: Works with `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}`

Comment: I get the same result when `Full` is replaced with `Automatic` (I'm running 9.0.1.0 if that matters).  Besides, I really want the behavior of `Full` and not `Automatic`.

Comment: @Bezewy: Probably one of those corner cases where MM's "try and make it pretty" heuristics fail, and you'll need to force it with something like `PlotRange->{Full,{0,Max@data}}`. FWIW, I see same behavior as you, 9.0.1 on windows, including same using *Oska*'s suggestion. Might be a regression if *Oska*'s on an earlier version, perhaps worth ping to WRI support.

Comment: @rasher: Thanks for checking the `Full` vs `Automatic` point.  As for `PlotRange->{Full,{0,Max@data}}` it also produces a negative y-axis for the all-zero case.

Comment: @Bezewy:Yep, just noticed that. So you'd need to provide some "minimum maximum" so to speak, like `PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 
   Max[1, Max@data]}}

Comment: @rasher: That works for me. Do you want to write it up as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Bezewy: Sure. One moment...

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/npRVcSY.png) is what I have with `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}` on _v8.0.4_ :)

Comment: @Öskå: Interesting. I'll try to pass this along to WRI Support, as suggested by Rasher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be one of those cases where the heuristics of "make it pretty" seems to fail (partially). If you want some set "floor" in this case, a construct like

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {Full, {0, Max[1, Max@data]}}]
```

should do the job.